# Embed Android dependencies in to Android library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to create an Android self-consistent library, that has inside external dependencies (like Retrofit). I want to use it in the main project without having to re-import all the library dependencies. Is it possibile?

this is my LIBRARY build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.lib"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.4.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
}
```

this is my APP build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // APP DEPENDENCIES
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    // LIB DEPENDENCIES
    compile 'my.lib:example:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0' //<--- I don't want to re-import this dependency
}
```

Comment: Are you using a maven repository?

Comment: yes, i use a maven repository

Comment: You can download the Jar file and add it in the Libs folder if that's what you mean -- https://github.com/square/retrofit

Comment: @user3299309 Check in your maven, the pom file. It should contain the dependencies.

Comment: @Tasos How does it resolve the issue?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti -- to be honest i did not understand the Q properly. I was under the impression the Q was asking access to the Retrofit Library.

Comment: @Tasos the user is expecting gradle is able to resolve the transitive dependencies. He isn't asking how to add retrofit library.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti -- ahh ok. i read somewere to resolve transitive dependencies  you compile like this -- compile ('dependency'){
       transitive=true
} -- but never tried myself yet.

Comment: i have try to add "transitive=true", but it doesn't work.

Comment: The transitive=true is require if you are using annotation as @aar in your dependency. In this case you should check the pom file in the maven to see if the dependencies are there.

Comment: any update on this? i want to do the same!